# Unity export to 64bit apk will cause the gameplay delay

Tags: unity-game-engine, export, apk, delay, 32bit-64bit

I have tried to export my game to mobile APK. When I'm export my game to 32-bit APK, everything is working fine and smooth 
But when I'm trying to export as 64-bit APK, the gameplay is a delay (eg: when I click a button, it need wait few seconds or more to have a response, this case is not happening in 32-bit APK). But the sound effect and background music is playing fine, didn't have any delay for the sound. 
Below is the setting for my 64-bit export

Setting:

[image: screenshot]

I will get these warning message after I exported, are these may caused my issue?

Warning Message:
[image: screenshot 2]

May I know have what issue or reason may cause this situation happen? Hope have someone able to helping me to solve this issue. Thank you

UPDATED:
I found reason is my script have to much FixedUpdate process in running to cause delay. So, I reduce the number of FixedUpdate to solve the problem.

May I know why 32-bit able to support the number of FixedUpdate, but 64-bit unable to support?

Answer (score 0):

On what device are you testing this? An Android emulator? This could be just an emulation problem and not be an issue on a modern real-world device.

Comment: I'm use real-world device to test it, I'm had use "build and run" to install into mobile device after exported as apk

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling stack trace option for debug logs.

You can find it in the player settings, at the bottom of "Other Settings"

Set "Stack Trace" for "Log" to "None"